# Gray Code Conversion

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map, boolean-algebra, code

[image: Question]

I'm aware that in Gray code the successive numbers will differ only by one bit. However I'm not able to proceed further.

Comment: Can you write the truth table to convert straight binary to gray code?

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of binary to gray conversion. Implementation in terms of XOR gates.

Comment: So, write down the truth table and see which lines are 1's for which output bits.

Comment: But the conversion is not from binary to gray. Gray equivalents for number 'n' and 'n+1' is given. Also how to relate h and g functions ?

Comment: So if you have the truth table for input 'n', it's very very easy to make the truth table for input 'n+1'.

Comment: Given the current code is (h3h2h1h0), the output of g() should be the next code in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking you the value of N where the value of Gx = 1 for N+1.

Map the current state N and Next state N+1 for the 4 bit Gray code

[image]

Read off the min term for each next case of Gx = 1

G0 = 0.1.6.7.12.13.10.11
G1 = 1.3.2.6.13.15.14.10
G2 = 2.6.7.5.4.12.13.15
G3 = 4.12.13.15.14.10.11

--> Answer = G2 is correct though they have the terms out of order in the question

Comment: Given g() is a function of H, I think you ought to re-sort the table according to H before numbering the minterms.

Comment: @ThePhoton. Feel free....it's pure choice. I prefer to work in sequence.